# Remove alphanum,num,email and other special char from the 6th field of a file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

My city field ie the 6th field has got addr,door #, email addr and some special char in it,which is getting my job harder.I wanted to replace numbers, email id,special char and other address from the CITY field of my file with blank space. I only want valid city names to be in there. I tried awk `awk -F'|' '$6 ~ /^[ ]*[0-9]{5}[ ]*$/'`, but this is not getting me what i want. Can anyone help me in advising the soln or tell me where i'm going wrong.I'm really great to have this participation here.Sorry for making this page so convoluted

My data be like:

NAME,AGE,LOC,NUM,ST,CITY,POSTAL,SAL,YEAR,STATUS1,STATUS2,STATUS3,S4

```
GARRY",30",US",7373",NY",NewYork",7900",100",2010",0",0",0",0
RAJ",40",IN",1291",IN",NewDelhi",8790",100",2012",1",1",1",1
KRIS",24",US",6328",NJ",9012 Cain Street",8739",200",2012",0",1",1",1
ROMY",57",IT",5623",OH",1900 Obama St #4",3434",200",2013",1",1",1",1
TIM",70",US",4004",CA",#205",9898",900",2017",1",1",1",1
STEVE",40",US",5656",WA",steveran@gmail.com",9123",289",2012",0",0",0",0
DONALD",34",US",3902",CA",donal@gmail.com",1290",300",2010",0",0",0",0
JABY",23",US",7800",WA",100-120",2900",100",2014",1",1",1",1
KOAY",25",US",8900",CA",Apt. P120",1000",100",2011",1",0",1",1
JAMES",30",US",3499",IN",B290",8900",200",2019",0",1",",1
JAKE",29",US",5609",MA",3091",4901",200",2019",1",1",1",0
JON",40",US",3490",IH",2901 Jakestall st 198",6790",100",0",0",",0",0
WAYNE",34",US",2679",WA",Washington",349",9",9",9",9",9",9
```

Output has to be:
 NAME,AGE,LOC,NUM,ST,CITY,POSTAL,SAL,YEAR,STATUS1,STATUS2,STATUS3,ST4

```
GARRY",30",US",7373",NY",NewYork",7900",100",2010",0",0",0",0
RAJ",40",IN",1291",IN",NewDelhi",8790",100",2012",1",1",1",1
KRIS",24",US",6328",NJ",",8739",200",2012",0",1",1",1
ROMY",57",IT",5623",OH",",3434",200",2013",1",1",1",1
TIM",70",US",4004",CA",",9898",900",2017",1",1",1",1
STEVE",40",US",5656",WA",",9123",289",2012",0",0",0",0
DONALD",34",US",3902",CA",",1290",300",2010",0",0",0",0
JABY",23",US",7800",WA",",2900",100",2014",1",1",1",1
KOAY",25",US",8900",CA",",1000",100",2011",1",0",1",1
JAMES",30",US",3499",IN",",8900",200",2019",0",1",",1
JAKE",29",US",5609",MA",",4901",200",2019",1",1",1",0
JON",40",US",3490",IH",",6790",100",0",0",",0",0
WAYNE",34",US",2679",WA",Washington",349",9",9",9",9",9",9
```

Comment: why did you say that this `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\","}; $6 ~ /[0-9@]/ {$6=""}; {print}'` isn't working? Seems to work fine

Comment: trust me it's not working. i've edited the header in the question, my header has no field framing. i'm using awk 3.1.7

Comment: trust me, it works on GNU Awk 4.1.3

Comment: How about `Hill Number 1`, the city name has a number in it.

Comment: Are you sure about your quotes? I would expect something like `"GARRY",30,"US",7373,"NY","NewYork",7900,100,2010,0,0,0,0`

Comment: This is a problem for the process that creates the file: that process needs to do a better job of validating the city field. Then again, if you allow users to type whatever they want, you have to deal with the results.

Comment: Hill Number 1 yes this one has to be eliminated as i need only city names anything that is not city has to be chucked. Yes my file is double quote delimited.

Comment: Why is your subject `Replace alphanum,num,email and other special char from the 6th field of a file with blank space` but then you aren't replacing anything with blank space in your output, you're just deleting some text? Fix whichever is wrong, the subject or the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$6=substr($6,1,length($6)-1);if ($6~/[^[:alpha:][:blank:]]/) $6=""}1' input.txt
```

breakdown:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}                         # input and output field separator is ","
{ $6 = substr($6,1,length($6)-1);         # get rid of trailing " in column 6
  if ($6  ~ /[^[:alpha:][:blank:]]/)      # if col 6 contains any char that's 
                                          #   not alphabetic or space
     $6=""                                # then empty col 6
}1                                        # print every line
```

Comment: does this include even removing special char from the field

Comment: No. Where do you want that removed? Just from column 6?

Comment: will it remove records like "New York". I see such records are wiped off as well. Is it possible to exclude such records from the elimination

Comment: some records have got special characters. they are like Apt #100 or blindly #123 or #.they need to be replaced as well.

Comment: sorry for confusion. Yes from field 6

Comment: moreover i'm still seeing digits (num) in that field.

Comment: Answer corrected to allow spaces, remove trailing " from column 6 and remove anything that's not a alphabetic char or space.

Answer (score 2):

Since the valid city names in your input are only alphabetic strings with multi-word city names (e.g. `New York`) concatenated to remove spaces (`NewYork`), all you need is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\","} $6 ~ /[^[:alpha:]]/ {$6=""} 1'
```

If you did need to allow spaces then this might be what you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\","} $6 !~ /^[[:alpha:][:space:]]+$/ {$6=""} 1'
```

or more strictly:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\","} $6 !~ /^[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+)*$/ {$6=""} 1'
```

but we'd need to see some representative input/output to figure that out for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Perl:

```
perl -F'",' -ae 'if($F[5] =~ /[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/) { $F[5] = ""; }; print join("\",", @F);' file
```

This works as follows:

- `-F'",'` sets the field separator to `",`, which is what your fields appear to be separated by,
- `-a` puts Perl into auto-split mode (`-a`), which makes it process input in a record-wise (by default line-wise) manner not unlike that of sed and awk and split each record into the special `@F` array along the supplied field separator, and
- `-e` makes it use the supplied expression for code.

So each line is split into fields and then further processed by

```
if($F[5] =~ /[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/) {    # If the sixth field contains something
                                          # other than a letter or space,
  $F[5] = "";                             # then make it empty
}
print join("\",", @F);                    # and print the (possibly modified)
                                          # fields, once again separated by ",
```

To tweak the behavior to suit your needs, you may want to fiddle with the regex or apply more sophisticated checks altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Usually awk is the better option for this kind of problem. As you seem to have problems with an older awk version on your system and you have the tag `sed`, this sed solution (tested with `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`) might work for you:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,"]*",){5})([A-Za-z ]*[^A-Za-z ",]+[A-Za-z ]*)*",/\1",/g' yourfile
```

- it matches five columns at line start (`^(([^,"]*",){5})`) and stores them away into `\1`
- then it *tries hard* to match your undesired content in the sixth column (`([A-Za-z ]*[^A-Za-z ",]+[A-Za-z ]*)*",`):

  - something not made up of characters spaces and `",` (`[^A-Za-z ",]+`) between optional valid words (the `[A-Za-z ]*` to the left and right)
  - and repetitions of such a string (`(...)*`)
  - followed by `",`
- such a string is replace by `\1",` with `\1` containing the value in the first five columns, thus deleting the content of the sixth column

Answer (score 0):

easy with **Perl** in 3 steps, like this:

```
~ ❱ perl -F'",' -e '$"="\",";$F[5]="" if $F[5]=~/ +|\d+|@/g;print "@F"' file 
GARRY",30",US",7373",NY",NewYork",7900",100",2010",0",0",0",0
RAJ",40",IN",1291",IN",NewDelhi",8790",100",2012",1",1",1",1
KRIS",24",US",6328",NJ",",8739",200",2012",0",1",1",1
ROMY",57",IT",5623",OH",",3434",200",2013",1",1",1",1
TIM",70",US",4004",CA",",9898",900",2017",1",1",1",1
STEVE",40",US",5656",WA",",9123",289",2012",0",0",0",0
DONALD",34",US",3902",CA",",1290",300",2010",0",0",0",0
JABY",23",US",7800",WA",",2900",100",2014",1",1",1",1
KOAY",25",US",8900",CA",",1000",100",2011",1",0",1",1
JAMES",30",US",3499",IN",",8900",200",2019",0",1",",1
JAKE",29",US",5609",MA",",4901",200",2019",1",1",1",0
JON",40",US",3490",IH",",6790",100",0",0",",0",0 
WAYNE",34",US",2679",WA",Washington",349",9",9",9",9",9",9
```

- `$"` array separator should be `",`
- 6th field (= `$F[5]`) is erased if there is `space` or `digit` or `@`
- print the result `@F`